# Combine multiple sequential Observables into one Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to combine the results of multiple http calls into one Observable. The calls must happen in order, each must wait for the previous one to end, and the number of http calls is not known until runtime.

I've seen similar questions, but the number of initial calls has always been known, and therefore, a couple of nested and/or chained pipe operations handled this easily. I will need to make 0-to-* API calls.

I *think* that `concatMap()` is the way to go, but I could be wrong. And I couldn't figure out the syntax to make it work.

```
// Post all phones to API individually, but return updated results in single array.
savePhones(phones: Phone[]): Observable<Phone[]> {

    let updatedPhones: Phone[] = [];

    if (phones.length === 0) {
        return of<Phone[]>(updatedPhones);
    }

    // I need to do something like this, but for 1 to **many** phones. 
    // When each Observable completes, add to array.
    // Only after the prior Observable completes, start the next.
    // When the last one is done, return the Observable array. 
    return this.postPhone(contactId, phones[0])
        .pipe(
            map(response1 => {
                let p1 = new Phone();
                p1.loadFromJson(response1);
                updatedPhones.push(p1);
            }),
            concatMap(() => this.postPhone(contactId, phones[1])
                .pipe(map(response2 => {
                    let p2 = new Phone();
                    p2.loadFromJson(response2);
                    updatedPhones.push(p2);
                }))),
            concatMap(() => this.postPhone(contactId, phones[2])
                .pipe(map(response3 => {
                    let p3 = new Phone();
                    p3.loadFromJson(response3);
                    updatedPhones.push(p3);
                }))),
            map(() => {
                return updatedPhones;
            })
        );

}

private postPhone(
    contactId: string,
    phone: Phone): Observable<Phone> {

    let criteria = phone.toJson();
    let url = phone.isNew()
        ? `${apiUrl}/contacts/${contactId}/phones/add`
        : `${apiUrl}/contacts/${contactId}/phones/${phone.phoneId}/update`;

    return this.httpClient.post(url, criteria));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So does the code you've posted work? Have you *tried* `concatMap`?

Comment: I could not figure out the syntax for concatMap to get anything to work. I'm not sure how to get an array of Observable<Phone> to work with it.

Comment: What do you mean the *syntax*? It's just a function you call: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap. Give a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated my sample code of what I'm trying to accomplish. However, it only works for a fixed number of phones.

Comment: Might want to checkout learn-rxjs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html They have lots of examples...

Answer (score 0):

Try forkJoin

```
savePhones(phones: Phone[]): Observable<Phone[]> {
    return phones.length === 0 ? of<Phone[]>([]) : forkJoin(phones.map(
      phone => this.postPhone(contactId, phone).pipe(
        map(response => new Phone().loadFromJson(response)),
      )
    ));
}
```

Comment: forkJoin Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they emitted. but in this case we want Combine multiple sequential Observables into one Observable so you could use Observable.mergeAll operator. 
see this link : http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll